# Cordova on Android showing black boxes with a cross

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome

My Cordova app on Android is showing these boxes with a black cross. Do you know why this happens? It doesn't occur on iOS.

[image: Example here]

Comment: does it occurs in web browser ?`cordova serve`.if so you can try inspect elements and find what are those elements

Comment: I'll test it in the browser today. I tried to inspect them with Chrome remote web inspector but I couldn't find the HTML associated item. It feels it is a character not being dispplayed properly but in the carousel I have no text.

Comment: if you can upload www folder we can test it